Google Script to Match Value between 2 workbooks and perform a series of actions on a match
Hi We have an issue where we need to update Workbook A with information found in Workbook B.
Workbook A has 30 Worksheets and Workbook B has only 1.
Ideally we are looking to match the values in Workbook B, Column A to ANY of Workbook A's Worksheets. On A successful match we would like to highlight the row in red and copy the matching Cell's Column E Value in Workbook B to the matching cell's Row under the first column with "Retired", "Retire Date" or "Retirement Date".
The aforementioned columns vary across Workbook A as far as which letter column they are in.
IF that is too complex, Alternatively we could try instead to return a hyper link to the matching cell in Workbook A and Manually copy the date and highlight the row.
I've been trying all sorts of methods to get this to stick and after several hours of research, a Google Script is what I believe to be the best bet on this. I'm unsure of what the best method or trigger is as I'm not very familiar with Google App Scripts.

This can indeed be accomplished with Google Apps Script.  Have you attempted writing the script?  The workflow would go something like this:

Open the Spreadsheet Workbook A

Get all sheets in the Workbook B into an array

Start for loop that iterates through each sheet in Workbook B.

On each sheet, get the display value of the headers (Row 1)
var sheetHeaders = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getMaxColumns).getDisplayValues();


Use the indexOf() to find the index of the column name in the header array and add 1, since the first position in an array starts at 0 (Column A = 1)
var columnNum = sheetHeaders.indexOf("Column Name") + 1;


Get All the display values in that column into an array and use the indexOf() to find the row of the match.
var columnValues = sheet.getRange(2,columnNum,sheet.getMaxRows()-1,1).getDisplayValues();
var rowNumber = columnValues.indexOf("Search Value")+2;


Now that you have the row number of the match you can write additional
script to edit the row and use the sheetHeaders array to update any column you'd like as long as you know the name of the column.

Loop through the remaining sheets repeating the process.


In summary, this can be done with some trial and error in Google Apps Script for a beginner. I have some working code I could share with you as well.

Thank you for the suggestion. They have completed the task for this year and will be re-creating the document with stricter parameters (Columns being identical between sheets) at our suggestion. Thank you!

Find matches in column A for both spreadsheets
function myfunk01() {
  const ssa = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.test1id);
  const shts = ssa.getSheets().filter(sh => ~sh.getName().indexOf("Sheet"));//I put the filter in here to protect my other sheets but you could remove it if you wish
  const ssb = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.ssid)
  const shb = ssb.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vsb = shb.getRange(1, 1, shb.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  let o = shts.map(sh => {
    let vs = [];
    if (sh.getLastRow() > 0) {
      vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      if (vs && vs.length > 0) {
        return vs.map((r, i) => {
          let idx = vsb.indexOf(r[0])
          if (~idx) {
            return { name: sh.getName(), row: i + 1, colE: r[4], matchv: vsb[idx] };
          }
        }).filter(e => e);
      }
    }
  }).filter(e => e);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o))
}

Returning an object with sheet name, row, colE value and matched value

Thank you for the suggestion. They have completed the task for this year and will be re-creating the document with stricter parameters (Columns being identical between sheets) at our suggestion. Thank you!
